# CDATE being selective in MDX

Tags: mdx

I have a problem with CDATE in MDX. Some months do not work for some reason.

```
Example:

CDATE("01-Januar-2015") -> 1/1/2015
CDATE("01-Februar-2015")-> 2/1/2015
CDATE("01-Mars-2015")   -> #Error
CDATE("01-April-2015")  -> 4/1/2015
CDATE("01-Mai-2015")    -> #Error
CDATE("01-Juni-2015")   -> 6/1/2015
CDATE("01-Juli-2015")   -> 7/1/2015
```

Sorry for the months name not being in English. For some reason march (mars), may (mai) and desember (december) gives error. As other month names works while still being language specific (Juni f.ex), it can't be that. Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: What locale identifier did you specify when you connected to run your query, if any? What is the install language for your SSAS instance?

Comment: I did not provide any locale identifier. Tbh I have no idea, but I recon this must be the right language as all the other language specific month names works.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty quickfix:

```
MEMBER Currentmonth AS
    CASE [Period].[Month name].currentmember.MEMBER_VALUE
    WHEN 'mars' THEN '03'
    WHEN 'mai' THEN '05'
    WHEN 'desember' THEN '12'
    ELSE [Period].[Month name].currentmember.MEMBER_VALUE
    END
```